# Error in uploading code on AWS CodeCommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-codecommit

Actually I want to integrate AWS CodeCommit with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But I am stuck in code upload on AWS CodeCommit. I have code of size 900 MB around. I have no idea so much about it so I am attaching image containing my problem related to hang process after completing the code upload process successfully. Please see the image for that. 
Actually, I have setup this parameter to increase the buffer size with following command:

> git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

**Main Issue is how we upload code of bigger size approx size in GB on aws codeCommit successfully.**

But, after that I am facing this issue so please if you have any idea about that, please help me. Thanks in advance.

[This is the image containing my problem definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmsSD.png)

Comment: Is there any wrong with the question then please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, it seems that you are under the limits of CodeCommit, which are listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/limits.html. I strongly suggest you to review them, just in case that you are falling in one of them.

Could you please provide more details about your git client, AWS region and try to run git push again with the GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 options?